# How would you program sprite movement in a 2-D ariel view rpg game?

Tags: java, 2d, animation, sprites, rpg

I'm relatively new to programming and I have recently programmed an RPG game in java.
Any tips on character movement with animations? I would like it to be similar to those of other rpg games such as Pokemon, Final Fantasy, ChronoTrigger etc.
[As seen in this demo, the current movement system that I have is pretty choppy and has no animation.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCBZJTVYTI4)

Comment: "I'm relatively new to programming and I have recently programmed an RPG game in java" Are you working backwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you developed the demo in the video on your own you should be able to understand what is needed for the movement animations. You need to post examples of attempts at coding the movement.

In simple terms;

You need to capture the movement event(s), you then need to specify which animation(s) to use in those events.